# HTTP Error 400 when trying to install PyGame via pip on Python 3.4.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, pip

I've been trying out PIP for Python, and I decided to try to use it to reinstall Pygame (I lost the Pygame I had during some Python file reshuffling I did).

I entered:

```
python -m pip install pygame --allow-external pygame --allow-unverified pygame
```

And it gave me the very lengthy error:

```
HTTP error 400 while getting http://www.pygame.org/../../ftp/pygame-1.6.2.tar.bz2 (from http://pygame.org/download.shtml)
Could not install requirement pygame from http://www.pygame.org/../../ftp/pygame-1.6.2.tar.bz2 because of error 400 Client Error: Bad Request
Could not install requirement pygame from http://www.pygame.org/../../ftp/pygame-1.6.2.tar.bz2 (from http://pygame.org/download.shtml).
```

What does all that mean & how do I fix it?

Comment: @KemyLand: `pip` is a software tool commonly used by programmers. Questions about such tools are perfectly on-topic here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Okay, you're right; the page I linked explicitly states so. So, I suppose there's no way to cancel my flag, no?

Comment: @KemyLand: Not really; I've just cleared the post from the review queue instead (noone had voted on the post yet).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Okay, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all an 400 error on a server means that the page or url that are you trying to achieve does not exist.
And for the way that you are trying to reinstall pyGame, shou should be using linux, so try this: sudo apt-get install python-pygame
If you are using MAC or windows go to http://pygame.org and  For Windows, download the pygame-1.9.1.win32-py3.2.msi file. (This is Pygame for Python 3.2 on Windows. If you installed a different version of Python (such as 2.7 or 2.6) download the .msi file for your version of Python.) The current version of Pygame at the time this book was written is 1.9.1. If you see a newer version on the website, download and install the newer Pygame.

For Mac OS X, download the .zip or .dmg file for the version of Python you have and run it.

Comment: So is there no version compatible w/ 3.4?